# Solspace Facebook Connect: Load Likes for a page

Tags: solspace-facebookconnect

I have a blog listing page. Under each of the 10 entries listed I would like to show how many likes that article has. Is there a way to do this with Facebook Connect Addon?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply put a facebook like button on each article:

http://www.solspace.com/docs/facebook_connect/fb_like_button/

That will show a count. I don't know if there is a way to get a count without showing the like button though. I suspect facebook wouldn't want you to do that.